# Top Rounded corners on node

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a rectangle node:

```
let shape = SKShapeNode()
shape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: -128, y: -128, width: 256, height: 256), cornerRadius: 64).CGPath
shape.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(frame), y:    CGRectGetMidY(frame))
shape.fillColor = UIColor.redColor()
shape.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor()
shape.lineWidth = 10
addChild(shape)
```

How do I add a border radius of 20 to the TopLeft and TopRight corners only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User this `UIBezierPath` initializer:

```
public convenience init(roundedRect rect: CGRect, byRoundingCorners corners: UIRectCorner, cornerRadii: CGSize)
```

and specify `[.TopLeft, .TopRight]` for the `byRoundingCorners` argument.

```
shape.path = UIBezierPath(
    roundedRect: CGRect(x: -128, y: -128, width: 256, height: 256),
    byRoundingCorners: [.TopLeft, .TopRight]
    cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 64, height: 64)).CGPath
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit nooby, I dont see how I get this to work with my already created SKNode.

Comment: @JamesG Updated my answer with sample usage

Comment: Oh, did I misunderstand your question? Are you asking about how to add borders? (the question title was misleading)

Comment: I am still a little confused with this public.... line. Anywhere I add it on my code I get errors like: Initializers must be declared within a type. or Initializer requires a body. Why is this not simple :/

Comment: @JamesG That *public* line was just an example of initializer (its declaration) which can be used to achieve what you want. It is not the code you should run. Everything below that is what you  need ;) This answer is correct.

Comment: Ah, It did work but there is an error in your code that was throwing me: byRoundingCorners: [.TopLeft, .TopRight] needs a comma after

Comment: also, It is changing the bottom corners, not the top. hmm lo l

Comment: @JamesG You might need to transform the path (flip it vertically) because SpriteKit's vertical coordinate system is different with UIKit's.